# Modify i-th next tensor values every time a value 1 appears in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have two tensors with the same size:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
b = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1]
```

Tensor *a* has three regions which are demarked by consecutive  values: region 1 is `[1,2,3,4,5]`, region 2 is `[10,11,12,13]` and region 3 is `[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]`.

For each of those regions, I want to apply the following logic: if one of the values of *b* is 1, then the following *i* values are set to 0. If they are already 0, they continue as 0. After *i* values are changed, nothing happens until another value of *b* is 1. In that case, the next *i* values are forced to 0...

Some examples:

```
# i = 1

a     = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
b_new = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1]


# i = 2

a     = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
b_new = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1]


# i = 4

a     = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
b_new = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1]
```

Not sure if this would help, but I was able to separate the regions into segments by doing:

```
a_shifted = tf.roll(a - 1, shift=-1, axis=0)
a_shifted_segs = tf.math.cumsum(tf.cast(a_shifted != a, dtype=tf.int64), exclusive=True)

# a_shifted_segs = 
= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Do you know any way of doing this efficiently?

Comment: How do you define the sections in a, when there is no jump, like a=range(1,29)

Comment: @Colim that would be a single region then

Comment: @Kunis are you sure the output for `i=4` is what you want? I would've expected `b_new = 1` when `a = 20`, not `a = 21`. If I am wrong, why does the difference between the segments matter?

Comment: @André you're right, that was a mistake. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure `Tensorflow` approach, which will work in `Eager Execution` and `Graph` mode:

```
# copy, paste, acknowledge

import tensorflow as tf

def split_regions_and_modify(a, b, i):
  indices = tf.squeeze(tf.where(a[:-1] != a[1:] - 1), axis=-1) + 1
  row_splits = tf.cast(tf.cond(tf.not_equal(tf.shape(indices)[0], 0), 
                    lambda: tf.concat([indices, [indices[-1] + (tf.cast(tf.shape(a), dtype=tf.int64)[0] - indices[-1])]], axis=0), 
        lambda: tf.shape(a)[0][None]), dtype=tf.int32)

  def body(i, j, k, tensor, row_splits):
    k = tf.cond(tf.equal(row_splits[k], j), lambda: tf.add(k, 1), lambda: k)
    current_indices = tf.range(j + 1, tf.minimum(j + 1 + i, row_splits[k]), dtype=tf.int32)

    tensor = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.equal(tensor[j], 1), tf.not_equal(j,  row_splits[k])), lambda: 
                  tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, current_indices[..., None], tf.zeros_like(current_indices)), lambda: tensor)
    return i, tf.add(j, 1), k, tensor, row_splits 

  j0 = tf.constant(0)
  k0 = tf.constant(0)
  c = lambda i, j0, k0, b, row_splits: tf.logical_and(tf.less(j0, tf.shape(b)[0]), tf.less(k0, tf.shape(row_splits)[0]))
  _, _, _, output, _ = tf.while_loop(c, body, loop_vars=[i, j0, k0, b, row_splits])
  return output
```

Usage:

```
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28])
b = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1])

split_regions_and_modify(a, b, 1)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(18,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>

split_regions_and_modify(a, b, 2)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(18,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>

split_regions_and_modify(a, b, 4)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(18,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a tensorflow solution, based on `tf.scan`. I know the conditionals are a bit complicated, if you have suggestions how to simplify, I'm open for suggestions. However, if you know how to read the conditionals, it should be quite clear what the code does.

Here, the variable `i` tells us, for each position in the array, how many more `b` values have to overwritten with `0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28])
b = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1])

# Extract switches inside a
switches = tf.scan(
    lambda e, new_a: {'a': new_a, 'out': new_a != (e['a']+1)}, 
    a, 
    initializer={'a': tf.reduce_min(a)-2, 'out': tf.constant(False)}
)['out']

# Define inputs for the scan iterations
initializer = {'b': tf.constant(False), 'i': tf.constant(0)}
elems = {'switches': switches, 'b': tf.cast(b, dtype=tf.bool)}

@tf.function
def step(last_out, new_in, max_i):
    new_i = tf.cond(
        last_out['i'] > 0, # If we are currently overwriting with 0
        lambda: tf.cond(
            new_in['switches'], # Is there a segment switch?
            lambda: tf.cond( # if switches:
                new_in['b'], # Check if b == 1
                lambda: tf.constant(max_i), # if b == 1: i = max_i
                lambda: tf.constant(0) # if b == 0: i = 0
            ),
            lambda: tf.maximum(last_out['i']-1, 0) # If no switch, decrement i
        ),
        lambda: tf.cond( # if we are currently not overwriting with 0
            new_in['b'], # check if b == 1
            lambda: tf.constant(max_i), # if b == 1: i = max_i
            lambda: tf.constant(0) # if b == 0: i = 0
        )
    )
    b = tf.cond(
        tf.equal(new_i, max_i), # Have we just reset i ?
        lambda: tf.constant(True), # If yes, we want to write b = 1
        lambda: tf.constant(False) # Otherwise, we write b = 0
    )
    
    return {'b': b, 'i': new_i}
```

Examples:

```
outp_1 = tf.scan(lambda _last, _inp: step(_last, _inp, max_i=1), elems=elems, initializer=initializer)
print( tf.cast(outp_1['b'], tf.int32) )
# tf.Tensor([0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1], shape=(18,), dtype=int32)

outp_2 = tf.scan(lambda _last, _inp: step(_last, _inp, max_i=2), elems=elems, initializer=initializer)
print( tf.cast(outp_2['b'], tf.int32) )
# tf.Tensor([0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1], shape=(18,), dtype=int32)

outp_4 = tf.scan(lambda _last, _inp: step(_last, _inp, max_i=4), elems=elems, initializer=initializer)
print( tf.cast(outp_4['b'], tf.int32) )
# tf.Tensor([0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1], shape=(18,), dtype=int32)
```

This answer is sponsored by lambda.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand well, you want in every section defined from list `a`, to keep the first `1` you meet in `b` then zero out the next `i` elements in this section in `b` and check again the rest elements if there is an `1` and apply the same logic (zero out the next `i` elements). then move to the next section etc. If I understand well a way to implement it is like this:

```
def get_new_b(a, b, i):
    sect_idx = []
    start_idx = 0
    new_b = b.copy()
    for idx in range(1, len(a)):  # Find sections of array a
        if (a[idx] - a[idx-1]) != 1 or idx == len(a) - 1:
            sect_idx.append([start_idx, idx])
            start_idx = idx

    for sect_start, sect_stop in sect_idx:
        for b_idx in range(sect_start, sect_stop):
            if new_b[b_idx] == 1:
                for b_zer in range(b_idx + 1, min(b_idx + 1 + i, sect_stop)):
                    new_b[b_zer] = 0
    return new_b
```

for:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]

b = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0, 1]
```

the results would be :

```
print(get_new_b(a=a, b=b, i=1))
print(get_new_b(a=a, b=b, i=2))
print(get_new_b(a=a, b=b, i=4))

>>> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```